# Why does my import urlopen from urllib.request not go through?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have the below code that I eventually want to webscrape and analyse.

My code has been running for almost an hour and it doesn't seem to pull through from this site.

---

```py
import bs4 as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq


my_url2 = 'https://www.dreamteamfc.com/g/#tournament/stats-centre-stats'

ureq(my_url2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you're looking for are loaded from other URL via Ajax (so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it). Also, use `requests` module for fetching the pages/Json data - it handles compression, redirects etc. automatically.

To load the data, use following example:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://nuk-data.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/json/players_tournament.json"
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data to screen:
for player in data:
    print(
        "{:<15} {:<15} {}".format(
            player["first_name"], player["last_name"], player["cost"]
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
Cristiano       Ronaldo         7000000
Goran           Pandev          1000000
David           Marshall        2000000
Jesús           Navas           3000000
Kasper          Schmeichel      3000000
Sergio          Ramos           5000000
Raúl            Albiol          2000000
Giorgio         Chiellini       3500000

...and so on.
```

---

EDIT: To load the data into a dataframe, you can use `.json_normalize`

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://nuk-data.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/json/players_tournament.json"
data = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=None)
```

Prints:

```
         id  first_name         last_name  squad_id     cost   status positions  locked injury_type injury_duration suspension_length cname  stats.round_rank  stats.season_rank  stats.games_played  stats.total_points  stats.avg_points  stats.high_score  stats.low_score  stats.last_3_avg  stats.last_5_avg  stats.selections  stats.owned_by  stats.MIN  stats.SMR  stats.SMB  stats.GS  stats.ASS  stats.YC  stats.RC  stats.PM  stats.PS  stats.CS  stats.GC  stats.star_man_awards  stats.7_plus_ratings  stats.goals  stats.assists  stats.cards  stats.clean_sheets  tournament_stats.star_man_awards  tournament_stats.7_plus_ratings  tournament_stats.goals  tournament_stats.assists  tournament_stats.cards  tournament_stats.clean_sheets
0     14937   Cristiano           Ronaldo       359  7000000  playing       [4]       0        None            None              None  None                 0                  0                   9                   0                 0                 0                0                 0                 0             22760            41.3        764          0          0        15          0         1         0         0         0         7         0                      0                     0            0              0            0                   0                                 0                                0                       0                         0                       0                              0
1     15061       Goran            Pandev       504  1000000  playing       [4]       0        None            None              None  None                 0                  0                   0                   0                 0                 0                0                 0                 0                50             0.1          0          0          0         0          0         0         0         0         0         0         0                      0                     0            0              0            0                   0                                 0                                0                       0                         0                       0                              0
2     15144       David          Marshall       115  2000000  playing       [1]       0        None            None              None  None                 0                  0                   0                   0                 0                 0                0                 0                 0               166             0.3          0          0          0         0          0         0         0         0         0         0         0                      0                     0            0              0            0                   0                                 0                                0                       0                         0                       0                              0
3     17740       Jesús             Navas       118  3000000  playing       [3]       0        None            None              None  None                 0                  0                   0                   0                 0                 0                0                 0                 0               154             0.3          0          0          0         0          0         0         0         0         0         0         0                      0                     0            0              0            0                   0                                 0                                0                       0                         0                       0                              0
4     17745      Kasper        Schmeichel       369  3000000  playing       [1]       0        None            None              None  None                 0                  0                   9                   0                 0                 0                0                 0                 0              3261             5.9        810          0          0         0          0         1         0         0         0         4         0                      0                     0            0              0            0                   0                                 0                                0                       0                         0                       0                              0
5     17861      Sergio             Ramos       118  5000000  playing       [2]       0        None            None              None  None                 0                  0                   9                   0                 0                 0                0                 0                 0             14647            26.6        712          0          0         1          0         1         0         0         0         6         0                      0                     0            0              0            0                   0                                 0                                0                       0                         0                       0                              0

...and so on.
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: this is very helpful thank you! How can I unstack the 'all data' results above into a dataset?

Comment: wow, so simply done, I can't believe it ! Thank you so much